# Proof of inequality of kurtosis

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let x1 and x2 be two random variable such that

1. $E[x_1]$ = $E[x_2]$ = 0
2. $E[x_1^2]$ = $E[x_2^2]$ = 1
3. $E[x_1^3]$ = $E[x_2^3]$ = 0
4. $E[x_1^4]$ <> $E[x_2^4]$
5. $E[x_1 *x_2] = \rho $

where $E(z)$ can be takes as $ \frac{\sum(z_i)}{ n}$

I read that in this case, there can't be a set of linear combinations that have equal kurtosis either

i.e there is no POSITIVE DEFINITE Matrix

$W = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2\\b_1 & b_2\end{bmatrix}$

$ y_1 = a_1 * x_1 + a_2 * x_2$

$  y_2 = b_1 * x_1 + b_2 * x_2$

such that

$ \frac{E[y_1^4]}{[E[y_1^2]]^2} = \frac{E[y_2^4]}{[E[y_2^2]]^2}$

Is there any intuition or proof of it?

Comment: what do you mean by $<>$? What exactly do you want to see. That if $\kappa(X)\neq\kappa(Y)$ ($\kappa$ stands for kurtosis) then for any linear combinations $aX+bY$ and $cX+bY$, $\kappa(aX+bY)\neq \kappa(cX+dY)$? Are there any conditions on $X$ and $Y$ (independence for instance?)

Comment: @OliverDiaz, '<>' means inequality. No conditions on X and Y - they may not be independent. The only condition is on linear combinations, i.e. the matrix formed with them should be positive definite

Comment: your formula of kurtosis is wrong unless your random variables have mean $0$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz sure you can assume zero mean. I don't believe that'll change the result though

Comment: No, but you need to make edits in your formula above. As a hint, every positive definition can be factored out as $A=P^*\Sigma A$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with positive number in the diagonal, and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix, that is $^*P=^*=I$, where $P^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $P$. Assume without loss of generality that $E[X]=0=E[Y]$ and $E[X^2]=1=E[Y^2]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Edited